# Why subprocess "sleep 10" does not terminate?

Tags: go, unix

I need to test if a process terminates and all I have is its pid number. To do so I test if the pseudo file "/proc/<pid>" exist.

Writing a test for this function, I noticed that the process doesn’t terminate as expected.

For the test, I run "sleep 10" as sub-process which should run for 10 seconds. After starting this process, I poll for the disappearance of the pseudo file "/proc/<pid>". That pseudo file never disappear and the termination of the sub-process is not detected.

Testing the code of golang playground reproduces the problem: https://play.golang.org/p/fb4CbXkIjh3.

I checked that the process is created, and that the pid is correct. While checking the process is seen that it turns into <defunct>. It isn’t thus removed.

The questions are the following:

1. why doesn’t the sub-process terminate ?
2. how can I change the code to make it terminate ?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os"
    "os/exec"
    "strconv"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Hello, playground")

    cmd := exec.Command("sleep", "10")
    if err := cmd.Start(); err != nil {
        log.Fatal("unexpected error:", err)
    }
    pidStr := strconv.Itoa(cmd.Process.Pid)
    log.Println("sleep pid:", pidStr)

    for {
        if _, err := os.Stat("/proc/" + pidStr); os.IsNotExist(err) {
            log.Println("detect termination of /proc/" + pidStr)
            return
        }
        log.Println("pgm /proc/" + pidStr + " is running")
        time.Sleep(3 * time.Second)
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not use cmd.Wait to wait for the program to exit?

Comment: You always have to call `wait` on a process.

Comment: @Volker because all I have is the pid. I don’t have *cmd*. This is just a test program. With the pid, the only wait I found to test if a program is terminated is to check if the pid is present in "/proc/".

Comment: However, if I add `go cmd.Wait()` just before the `for` loop, the program behaves as expected. The sub-process is not flagged as `defunct`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At the OS level, in any POSIX-compatible OS (Unix, Linux, Darwin, etc), a process that has completed, but not yet been collected by its superior, is in "defunct" or "zombie" state.  It still exists, but cannot be killed: it is already dead.  It exists precisely so that its superior—the process that *can* call the OS level `wait` system call—can call the OS level `wait` system call and *see* that the process is now dead.

Once its superior has waited for it, the process is truly removed: there is no longer a zombie process hogging that process ID.  If you have a `/proc` file system, this is when the process vanishes from `/proc`.

In Go, calling `cmd.Wait()` invokes the OS-level `wait` call, so that is the way to do this.  If you would like to collect the result of this `cmd.Wait()`, a good way to do that is to send it through a channel.

(If you want to spawn a very long running process and not wait for it, you can *disown* it, so that you are no longer its superior.  The details on doing this correctly are full of OS-specific doodads, such as discarding control ttys, setting sessions, using `procctl` or `prctl`, and so on.)